# Getting a unique ID for a window of another application

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

I'm a newbie Cocoa developer and I'm developing my first application. I want to read a unique identifier from any window of any application - whether it's Cocoa or Carbon. Cocoa applications make their window IDs available to AppleScript (although I'm sure there's a much better way to do this through a proper Objective C route), but I'm trying to access window IDs from documents in the Adobe apps. This seems to be a lot trickier. All I can seem to find in the reference libraries is [HIWindowGetCGWindowID](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Window_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/HIWindowGetCGWindowID):

"This function returns the window ID assigned by the window server when a window is created. The window ID is not generally useful with any other Carbon function, but may be used with other Mac OS X functions that require a window ID, such as functions in OpenGL."

Can this be used to get the ID from my program? Or is it just a function that can be used within one application?

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the window ID you receive?

Comment: I'm making a time tracking application and I want to get the active document path. Grabbing the window ID of the active window means I can track time for unsaved documents and means that I have a unique ID for when the file is removed or renamed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function `HIWindowGetCGWindowID()` can only return a `CGWindowID` for one of your app's windows, since a `WindowRef` from another program won't be valid in yours.

The function `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` from *CGWindow.h* will return an array of dictionaries, one for each window that matches the criteria you set, including ones in other applications.  It only lets you filter by windows above a given window, windows below a given window and "onscreen" windows, but the dictionary returned includes a process ID for the owning app which you can use to match up window to app.  In each returned dictionary the `kCGWindowNumber` key will point to the window ID as a `CFNumber`.  There is also a `CGWindowListCreate()` function that only returns an array of `CGWindowID`s.  There is basically no documentation for these functions beyond the *CGWindow.h* header and the [Son of Grab](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/SonOfGrab/index.html) sample code.  Also, it's 10.5 only.

Comment: Fantastic. Thankyou so much Boaz! Stack Overflow rules.