# Get the Focused Window on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm want to get the focused window reference in my Cocoa App and I really don't know how. I've read some articles about Accessability API and others about CGWindow but it still not Clear. I got to be able to determine the position of the current focused window, even though it's not from my application (It would be an iTunes Window or a Finder window).

Answer (score 1):

The first window in `[NSApp orderedWindows]` should fit your needs.

Comment: That will only return the questioner's own windows, not any other applications' windows.

Comment: So How can I get at least the active (focused) window on the system, even though this window don't belong to my application?? I really need a reference of that window.

Comment: This can get you a bit further : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311956/getting-a-unique-id-for-a-window-of-another-application, and this too : http://stackoverflow.com/a/373210/840518

Comment: I've managed to get the whole process list by using CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo which gives me a array full of Dictionaries with the process data. However There are so many other process that don't match an application window. How can  I retrieve only the focused window reference???? Thank you =D

Answer (score 0):

I realize this doesn't quite answer your question, but if you're willing to settle for the current *application* instead of the currently focused *window* then you should use the `currentApplication` method of `NSRunningApplication`. More [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRunningApplication/currentApplication).